# What's the best way to copy xib file(s)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I have a ViewController.xib that I would like to duplicate so I can make some settle changes to the duplicate copies. Everything is laid out how I like it in interfaceBuilder and coded correctly in the original ViewController(.M & h.). Can this be done and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't a way to directly duplicate a file from within Xcode. I've submitted a bug to Apple on this and you should too. It's not too difficult to do manually, though:

1. In Xcode, right-click on the xib and choose "Show in Finder"
2. Once Finder comes up with the file selected, right-click on the file and choose "Duplicate"
3. Rename the file as you need
4. Drag these new files back into your Xcode project.

Comment: Once item is copied, will the original code overlap with all the copies made?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you are asking if the new xibs will point to the same .h/.m files, then the answer is yes. You can use init:withNibNamed: to load the one you want to see. In general, you want to have a single viewController and multiple xibs rater than duplicating xibs and VCs.

Comment: My plan is to copy xib file, make a few changes per new copy, and then code up the changes per xib file. Would I need to copy the original m. and H. to make this happen? Thanks for you help!

Comment: In this case, why do you need to duplicate any of the files?

Answer (score 0):

Using FINDER, duplicate all three files and rename them.

Drag them back into the project in Xcode.

Rename the Class in the .h & .m files & start making your subtle changes.

However, if your changes are all just to do with positioning you could just use the one file and change the frames of the things you're moving about

OR

Just duplicate the XIB file, rename it appropriately, add to the project & make the subtle changes. Then you can load the ViewController with whichever XIB suits your needs...

Comment: My changes will mostly be made in InterfaceBuilder. There will be  very little code added to the new copies. So which way is better?

Comment: Well, if the new copies require code added, you might be better off copying all 3 files. That way your .m file won't have a bunch of conditional statements for each XIB type.